# Why dont work this java program?

Tags: java, regex

I want get [This imageurl.txt](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4bPCqeXhvHcYTR3R3VRY29SNHc) file, from [this source.txt](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4bPCqeXhvHcVFNBSnItT016S1E) , with the program.
If i try only with "p" or "p2", then works. But both the two pattern, writes out ,nothing.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.io.*;

public class imageurl
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException
    {
    for ( int i = 1; i < 5000; i++ )
        {
        toContent(i);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cacheimages/(.*)[\"][ ]*target=");
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("</b>[ ]*[(](.*)[)]</div>");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("source\\source"+i+".txt"));
        String line;
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("imageurl\\imageurl"+i+".txt");
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null )
            {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(line);
            while (m.find())
            while (m2.find())
                {
                String c = (m.group(1));
                String c2 = (m2.group(1));
                System.out.println("<name>"+c2+"</name>_<url>http://www.geocaching.hu/cacheimages/"+c+"</url>"+"\n");
                writer.write("<name>"+c2+"</name>_<url>http://www.geocaching.hu/cacheimages/"+c+"</url>"+"\n");
                }
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
    private static void toContent(int i)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't simply duplicate every line.  You have inadvertently nested two `while` loops:  `while (m.find()) while (m2.find())`

Comment: Make sure you understand the basic concepts of programming, and the syntax of the language, *before* you post here.

Comment: What can i do with duplicate line?

Comment: Please help me! How can i to improve this program?

Comment: split your `while() while()` cycle into two different cycles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the two expressions you're matching don't exist on the same line at the same time.  You need to read two lines at once to get the results you want.

```
. . .
String line2;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null )
    Matcher m=p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        if (line2 = r.readLine() != null) {
            Matcher m2=p2.matcher(line);
            if (m2.find()) {
                String c=m.group(1);
                String c2=m2.group(1);
                String outmsg=String.format("<name>%s</name>_<url>http://www.geocaching.hu/cacheimages/%s</url>\n", c2, c);
                System.out.print(outmsg);
                writer.write(outmsg);
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how can i use this. Maybe, can you send me the complet code?

Comment: @phatfingers, I think that you have done all you can to lead this horse to water.  By the way, the links to the sample input and desired output don't seem to work any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have for every `m.find()` one `m2.find()` then it is ok if you have only one `while` and an `if` instead of the second `while`.

Else if you have more `m2.find()` for one `m.find()` then you have to check if the positions of `m2.find()` is between the two `m.find()` (the correct one and the next one).